# How does the bind operator get invoked multiple times

Tags: haskell

First I would like to apologize if I am not asking the correct question. I realize that there are some fundamental concepts that I don't quite understand about Monads and the bind operator which is making it difficult to formulate my question. I am having a hard time wrapping my head around how the following code is creating a list of tuples.

```
ordPairs :: Ord a => [a] -> [(a, a)]
ordPairs xs =
   xs >>= \x1 ->
   xs >>= \x2 ->
   if x1 < x2 then [(x1, x2)] else []

main = print $ ordPairs [1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 9, 7, 8, 45, 4]
```

I understand the type declaration states that it returns a list of tuples `[(a, a)]`. What I can't figure out is how is this code "looping" through each item in the list? Looking at this as a beginner it looks as if it only passes the first and second item forward `x1 and x2` and then ends with the `if then else` expression. Is this code being desugared into multiple iterations and building the list under the hood? I guess what I am asking is how is this code iterating through each item in the list and building a list of tuples at the end?

Comment: for a list, `>>=` is `flip concatMap`.

Answer (score 5):

It might help to understand "where the parentheses are".   The right-hand side of the `ordPairs` definitions is parsed like this:

```
xs >>= (\x1 -> xs >>= (\x2 -> if x1 < x2 then [(x1, x2)] else []))
```

As you can see here, the `if-then-else` expression does not stand alone, it's actually the body of an anonymous function:

```
\x2 -> if x1 < x2 then [(x1, x2)] else []
```

which can, obviously, be invoked multiple times for different values of `x2`.  What invokes it?  Well, the second `>>=` operator, of course.  The "outer" loop works similarly, with the first `>>=` operator invoking another anonymous function multiple times:

```
\x1 -> xs >>= (\x2 -> ...)
```

For this example, you could replace the `>>=` operator with your own custom `bind` function.  Note that it's just a plain function.  There's no special desugaring or secret iterating going on.  The function itself does the iterating using recursion:

```
bind :: [a] -> (a -> [b]) -> [b]
bind (x:xs) f = f x ++ bind xs f
bind [] _ = []
```

You could also write `bind` like this, if you prefer:

```
bind xs f = concatMap f xs
-- or even `bind = flip concatMap`, as per @WillemVanOnsem's comment
```

Or as a list comprehension.

```
bind xs f = [y | x <- xs, y <- f x]
```

This last one is the actual definition of the `>>=` operator for the list monad.  See [GHC/Base.hs](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-18.27/base-4.14.3.0/src/GHC-Base.html#instance%20Monad%20%5B%5D).

With any of these definitions, the following will work just like your original:

```
bind :: [a] -> (a -> [b]) -> [b]
bind (x:xs) f = f x ++ bind xs f
bind [] _ = []

ordPairs :: Ord a => [a] -> [(a, a)]
ordPairs xs =
   xs `bind` \x1 ->
   xs `bind` \x2 ->
   if x1 < x2 then [(x1, x2)] else []

main = print $ ordPairs [1,2,4,6,7,8,4,5,6,2,9,7,8,45,4]
```

Comment: Oh of course, recursion!

Comment: Your comment about "where the parentheses are" and mentioning recursion was the missing piece I needed to understanding this.

Comment: I think mentioning how the List Monad is defined would be helpful here too. Would you be able to touch on that in your answer?

Comment: @technoY2K list monad is defined by `xs >>= f  =  bind xs f  =  concatMap f xs`.

Comment: I've added a note with a reference to the actual definition of `>>=` in the `Monad []` instance.